# How to write to a NEW LINE and not always on the same line in a text file after a UNIQUE file.write request?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've got a program to write to a text file. It works great, however there is an issue:

I want it so the program will write to a NEW LINE after each call, so for example:

I make a first call to writing the word "test1" into the textfile, it does that fine.

But then afterwards I put a command to write a word "test2". It just overwrites the first word, "test1" but I want it to be on a separate line?

Please note I am not doing everything at once as the whole point of my program is to save each command to write something into the text file as separate lines.

Code so far:

```
fixRes = (var1, ":", var2, ":", var3, ":", var4,)
            fixtureTXT = open("fix.txt", "w")
            fixtureTXT.writelines("\n")
            fixtureTXT.writelines(fixRes)
            fixtureTXT.writelines("\n")

            fixtureTXT.close()
```

Comment: Are you re-opening the file each time you want to write to it? Why are you opening it with `'r+'` when all you do is write to it?

Comment: Hi Martijn. I have changed it to a "w" now. However nothing changed in terms of the actual program

Comment: Use `'a'` to append. `r+` puts the file position *at the start* of the file, `'w'` *truncates* (clears) the file when opening. `'a'` *appends* to the end of the file.

Comment: Thank you EVER SO MUCH! It worked. Is it possible to choose your comment as the best answer as you said it via a comment?

Comment: Already posted it as an answer below; you can mark that as accepted instead (once your post is 15 minutes old).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are re-opening the file for writing each time, and the `'w'` mode *clears* the file first.

If you wanted to *append* to the file, use `'a'` instead:

```
fixtureTXT = open("fix.txt", "a")
```

If you open the file with the `with` statement, as a context manager, you don't have to call `.close()` on it:

```
with open("fix.txt", "w") as fixtureTXT:
    fixtureTXT.write("\n" + fixRes + "\n')
```

is then enough.